# Colocar ícone e exibir o nome do arquivo dependendo da extensão dele

Tags: php, html, ajax

Ultimamento tenho mexido com uploads de arquivos, exibição dos mesmos com PHP e etc... e me veio uma dúvida a cabeça, dei uma pesquisada mas não encontrei algo certo.

**De que maneira eu possa chegar perto de fazer um `preview` de arquivos  ou até mesmo brincar com o css nele, colocando uma imagem e o nome do arquivo?**

> *Porém dependendo da extensão dele, se a extensão for `DOCX` exibe um icon do word e em baixo o nome do arquivo, etc....*

Existe alguma biblóteca para isso ou algum script?

O `preview` que eu gostaria é esse (gmail): obviamente podem ser outros também...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Já estou exibindo os meus arquivos normalmente, apenas quero colocar um `preview` na exibicação de cada arquivo...

Como eu exibo:

```
<?php

require('conexaobd.php');

$sql = "SELECT relatorio.*, pacientes.nome, pacientes.data_saida FROM relatorio,pacientes WHERE relatorio.paciente=pacientes.nome";

$resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$inc = 0;


while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {

    echo '
        <tr>



echo $cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica'] != "" ? "<td><a href='ver-arquivo.php?documento=uploads/uploadsed/{$cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica']}' title='{$cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica']}' target='_blank'><img src='images/icon/bola.png' style='width:40px; height:40px;cursor:pointer;'></a></td>" : "<td></td>";


echo $cont['relatorio_enfermagem'] != "" ? "<td><a href='ver-arquivo.php?documento=uploads/uploadsenf/{$cont['relatorio_enfermagem']}' title='{$cont['relatorio_enfermagem']}' target='_blank'><img src='images/icon/enf.png' style='width:40px; height:40px;cursor:pointer;'></a></td>" : "<td></td>";

';

?>
```

Comment: da para fazer só com CSS, mas inclui ai o seu código na pergunta

Comment: Pronto @hugocsl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse exemplo eu fiz com `src` e imagens (`.jpg` e `.gif`), mas vc pode adaptar para `href` e a extensão que precisar (`.doc` e `.pdf`)

Aqui tem um exemplo, se a tag `img` tiver no src uma imagem que termina com `.gif` ou `.jpg` no final da imagem ela `exibe` um ícone diferente na tag `<i>`

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
}

[src*=".jpg"] + .jpg,
[src*=".gif"] + .gif {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url(https://www.zamzar.com/images/filetypes/jpg.png);
}

[src*=".gif"] + .gif {
  background-image: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698352-icon-130-document-file-gif-512.png);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://t2.uc.ltmcdn.com/pt/images/4/5/8/img_diferenca_entre_jpg_e_jpeg_8854_600_square.jpg"> <i class="jpg gif"></i>

<br>

<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Madeiraflag.gif"> <i class="jpg gif"></i>
```